# Best Practices ElseIf against Throw Exception

Tags: java

In Java: Which is the most performance code and why?

```
if (x==1) {
    ....
} else if (x==2) {
    ....
} else if (x==3) {
    ....
} else if (x==4) {
    ....
}
... rest code here...

or 

try {
    if (x==1) {
        ... 
        throw MyException(1);
    }
    if (x==2) {
        ... 
        throw MyException(2);
    }
    if (x==3) {
        ... 
        throw MyException(3);
    }
    if (x==4) {
        ... 
        throw MyException(4);
    }
} catch(MyException MEx) {
    ... rest code here ...
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should use switch you know

Comment: Possibly use a switch--but remember that switches (and blocks of code like the ifs question) are a bad code smell.  In this case what he probably wants is a table lookup into a data structure, but could need more.. would depend on what is inside the {....}, but you virtually never want to see if/else blocks like the one listed.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it strikes me as very odd when a standard feature of any language as switch is labeled a 'bad code smell'.

Comment: @Adriano Varolu Piazza - GOTO is a standard feature of some programming languages... that doesn't mean you should use it.  In this case the 'bad code smell' is because in most cases that a switch or set of if...else statements is used in place of polymorphism - creating a kind of 'choke point' for adding behavior in your program rather than allowing it to be extendable or controllable by the objects themselves.  The refactoring is 'Replace Conditional with Polymorphism' - http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html

Comment: @Nate: if we're talking about OOP, or at least 'intelligent structs' sure (yes, yes, the example is Java). That's not always the case. Plus, adding as a solution using a table lookup as in Bill K's comment isn't changing much from the polymorphism POV, or is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your example, you are using exceptions for flow control. Exceptions are expensive operations (or, at least, significantly more expensive than `if` and `else-if` blocks). Exceptions should only be used for exceptional situations.

Also, using `else if` will ensure that the checking stops as soon as a matching case is found. Using just `if` will check all of them all the time, and any matching cases will be executing. If you have many cases and they are ordered by the most common cases toward the top, using `if-else-if` will perform better.

Comment: +1 for commenting that the two blocks actually do different things.

Comment: Usign if with throw i have no to execute other cases, any way... now it's clear for me that exceptions are more expensive than else if. 
Thanks a lot Thomas!

Answer (score 4):

Others have answered your question, but I thought I'd point out...

Just because Java doesn't have the "goto" command (implemented), doesn't mean you should use Exceptions to simulate them.

Answer (score 2):

Not only will the second version have worse performance, it's also quite confusing to the reader and not how exceptions are meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the two are not comparable. Why put the "rest of code" in the second example in an exception handler, when that exception is not mentioned in the first example? If that exception is certain to be thrown, then "rest of code" in the first will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You get more performance when *not* using exceptions. But exceptions are special kind of structure and not to be confused with control flow structures such as `if-else`.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm a big fan of switch statements but isn't this like a textbook situation to use them?

```
    switch (x) {
    case 1:

        break;
    case 2:

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
...
```

Comment: It depends. In this particular example, since everything is compared using ==, a switch would work. However, if you wanted to potentially execute multiple blocks, using ==, <, >, <=, and >=, then the if/else-if would be better.

Comment: Nick, you messed up your switch statement, you only need one switch(x) and add a default:

Comment: Thanks Dan, trying to be fast isn't always a good idea ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> *...Which is the most performance code*

The if/elseif construct.

> *and why?*

Because the later involves the creation of an object of type MyException ( which internally may fill the stacktrace, allocate memory for the object, assign variable with the exception code )

Although the difference may not perform that worst at first sight, it is definitely a bad use of exception.

I could give you ( or try to  ) an explanation about it, but better is for you to read it from an authority on the matter:

Effective Java item:  [Use exception for exceptional conditions](http://bit.ly/HQRgF).

By Joshua Bloch.